# FormType add field from entity relation

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 4 project I have a **ParametersAdmin** entity which contains a **OneToOne** relation with the **Entreprise** entity.

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise", mappedBy="parametresAdmin", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $entreprise;
```

The **Entreprise** entity has a **nom** field

In my form which is based on **ParametresAdmin** entity, I would like to include the **entreprise.nom** property.

So, I tried this :

```php
->add('entreprise', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => "Nom de l'entreprise",
                "class" => Entreprise::class,
                "choice_label" => "nom",
                "required" => false,
            ])
```

I have now the **nom** value, but it's like a **ChoiceType** and not a **TextType**

[image]

Comment: the behavior you describe is working as intended. So up from there it's just ... guesswork for now. So I assume you want something like an autocompletion text input, to select another entreprise? or do you want to be able to *edit* the text (nom) of the entreprise?

Comment: I would like a simple text entry, like with a TextType, so I would be able to edit the text (nom) of the entreprise

Comment: I know the code behaves the way I coded it, that is, as ChoiceType. My goal is to develop this code so that I can edit the **nom** value entirely, as you say in the first comment (and sorry for bad english I'm French)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

editing the value of a subentity of the entity you're editing is fairly easy.

you would have to change the type of the form to TextType, as you have probably already assumed, and give the form information on where the data is located on your "parent" entity, this can be done via the [`property_path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) option:

```
->add('entreprise_nom', TextType::class, [
      'label' => "Nom de l'entreprise",
      'property_path' => 'entreprise.nom', // <--- this
      'required' => false,
])
```

`entreprise.nom` essentially tells the form component that it should first access the `entreprise` property on your entity, and on that value it should access the `nom` property (you can read more about this on the [property access(or) doc page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html)). It will also change (!) the `nom` property on `entreprise`, if the form is submitted and the entity manager flushed.

Comment: Yes, it's perfect ! Thank you very much :D